# How can I read data from DataTap using cpython?

Tags: bluedata, hpe-container-platform, ezmeral

I would like to read data from DataTap using cpython.

In spark, I can do something like:

```py
df = spark.read.csv("dtap://MaprClus2/tmp/airline-safety.csv")
```

How can I do the same if I am using cpython, for example when I don't have a pyspark Jupyter kernel?

Comment: Did you find any other way to achieve this i.e. other than using hadoop cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a subprocess to call out to the `hadoop` cli command:

```py
from subprocess import check_output
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

def hdfs_read(fpath):
    out = check_output(['hadoop', 'fs', '-cat', fpath])
    return BytesIO(out) 

data = hdfs_read("dtap://MaprClus2/tmp/airline-safety.csv")

# row 1 contains hadoop cli warning so remove it
pd.read_csv(data, sep=",", skiprows=1)
```

Comment: That's a valid answer. Is there any more pythonic solution? Any package that supports dtap reads in python?

Comment: Yes - using PyArrow and Pydoop.  The setup is manual at the moment, however, I'm hoping the next release will automate the setup.  I'll post a new answer if that happens.